# Is it possible to specify only some template parameters when calling a function template and let the compiler deduce the others

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction, function-templates

Consider the following function template:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void foo(T1 a, T2 b){// Do something.}
```

Now assume that I want `T1` to be `int`, but `T2` to be deduced by the compiler depending on the type of `b`. Something like `foo<int,...>(1,b)`. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes!

```
foo<int>(1, b);
```

But in that example above there is no benefit. The difference is visible if your first argument would not already be deduced to `int`:

```
foo<int>(3.2f, b);
//       ^^^^ Implicit conversion
```

Comment: Note that you cannot specify _only_ the second argument. If you leave one argument to be deduced, it will always be the last one, i.e. `T2`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Quentin is most convenient.

But there is other way to solve the issue to obvious to come up with it. Since forcing specific template type leads to silent conversion, sometimes it might be more wise to just do explicit conversion.

```cpp
double x = 1.1;
foo(static_cast<int>(x), boost::lexical_cast<int>(y));
```

Classic example is use of `std::move` which only converts to xvalue.